# Why would an Akka actor send a reply to itself?

Tags: akka

I have an integration test which sends a lot of messages to a remote Akka (2.0.5) actor. After each test run, the remote actor tree is restarted. After 43 successful test runs, according to the debug-level log messages, the remote actor started to send replies to itself, which obviously caused the test to fail.

Why might this happen?

There is only one place in the codebase where I am sending these type of messages, and it clearly says

```
sender ! generateTheMessage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why it's happening in my particular case. There are actually two actors involved here:

```
A -> B
```

A initially queues up messages until the system is initialised. Then it sends the queued up messages on to B, and forwards all further messages to B as soon as they arrive.

The problem is that when it forwards the queued up messages, the original sender information has been lost and so A becomes the sender. So the reply from B goes back to A and is forwarded back to B again. I didn't initially realise the latter forwarding was happening, because I hadn't enabled logging for the forwarding.

So it's a race condition. If the system comes up quickly enough everything is OK, but if not, some initial replies will be misdirected.

How I fixed this was to pair up the sender with each queued message, and resend each queued message using the Java API, which allows specifying the sender explicitly.